# Styling for google search app pages

Tags: html, css, google-search, google-search-appliance

I am currently working on a project and mobile design is great and works well except for when using the google search app.

I have buttons at the bottom of the page which work on all mobile browsers except on google search app. When clicking the buttons the bottom bar of the search app opens and doesn't allow click.

My answer is to move the buttons up with styling so that these will not interfere with the app but how do i apply the styling to move these specifically to the google search app app and not apply to all other mobile browsers?

can anyone help?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: the code wont really help here as need to  really know if we can specifically stylign for google search app

Comment: The button is position fixed and has a bottom of 20px, i amended this to 60px, but this styling amend will apply to all mobile browsers and we want to specifically target for google search app

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP to check for the user agent. if it contains "PSA" it means it is the google search browser. you can then define an IF that will modify the CSS code in that case.